# Sublime Package Control Shortcut in Windows

Tags: sublimetext3

On my Mac I can open up the Sublime Text 3 package explorer using Cmd+Shift+P. How can I do this on my windows machine? ctrl+Shift+P doesn't work for me and a google search yielded nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> is the default key binding for the Command Palette on Windows (and Linux). If it's not working for you, click on the `Tools` menu and see what shortcut is listed next to the `Command Palette` option (it should be the first entry in the menu).